# Spring boot : Add static web page (Angular) in a custom folder outside classpath folder (classes)

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, web-config

How would I place the static contents in a WAR Archive.
I have tried placing them inside the classes folder and works fine, but to make the cleaner I am asked to put it outside the WEB-INF, in a custom folder. I was able to do that and make it work by setting the welcome page in web.xml

```
<welcome-page>'./app/index.html'</welcome-page>
```

But the issue is that I don't want *'app'* to appear in my URL, when the pages were kept inside *classes/static* the index.html appeared in root(localhost:8080), but putting the pages in custom folder URL changed to - localhost:8080/app
Is there any way to keep the pages in a custom folder and still get the index page and its dependencies from root URL.

Comment: In a typical Spring Boot application you'll have a src\main\webapp folder, where you can place web resources. Does that work?

Comment: But if I recall, after project build the pages is placed inside classes folder. I need the pages in a custom folder outside the WEB-INF folder. Any idea on how to achieve that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you place your resources under "src/main/webapp", these will be copied to the root of your WAR. If you need more flexibility, maybe the maven-war-plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <webResources>
        <resource>
          <directory>${project.basedir}/mycustomdir</directory>
          <targetPath>somewhere</targetPath>
        </resource>
      </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```